# Segoe SemiBold font is not working in Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, fonts, windows-phone-8.1

In our app we use normal, bold & semibold types of Segoe UI fonts.
In the designer all these 3 looks different as expected however on device (or simulator) semibold fonts are not working properly it looks same as bold.

I have also tried with "Segoe UI SemiBold" font instead of "Segoe UI" but the result is same.

Following is the code:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="Hello World!" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="30" />
        <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="Hello World!" FontFamily="Segoe UI SemiBold" FontSize="30" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="Hello World!" FontFamily="Segoe UI Bold" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" />
</StackPanel>
```

Also, attached screen shots from designer & simulator.
[image: Designer Screenshot]
[image: Simulator Scrrnshot]

In designer we can see the difference between all 3 fonts while in simulator semibold & bold looks similar.

Answer (score 0):

Settings font family is not ideal. The preferred that works is setting `FontWeight` instead.

Comment: I have tried with setting FontWeight also. Same font family and different weight but result is same. SemiBold & Bold looks similar.